# Issue in Ray reflection forumla

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am making a ray tracer so I needed to reflect a ray of a sphere, following the equation Rout = Rin - (2* Rin * N') *N it seem to have an issue.
I tried to make the test the same values on matlab however the issue is still present. is there is an issue with the equation ?

```
Normal = [1.6667 -0.8333 1.6667]
#Ray in
Rin= [-5 -1.25 -5]
#Ray out forumla
Rout = Rin - (2* Rin * Normal') *Normal 
#Rout = [47.0856  -27.2912   47.0856]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Normal is not normalized

```
Normal = [1.6667 -0.8333 1.6667]
#Ray in Rin= [-5 -1.25 -5]
#Ray out forumla Rout = Rin - (2* Rin * normr(Normal)') *normr(Normal)
```